# quirks with mysql workbench table editor data updates?

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I've noticed some quirks with MySQL Workbench when I try to update table data directly through the MSW table editor.  One example is that I have a table with a BIT column.  If I change the value from 0 to 1 or from 1 to 0 and then click the Apply button, MSW opens a dialog with the Update SQL to be executed.  When I click the OK button to execute the auto-generated SQL, MSW reports that the update SQL statement is invalid.

When I take a look at the generated SQL, the problem is that MySQL wraps the updated BIT value in quotes.  So obviously that's a type mismatch.  Any idea why I might be experiencing this quirk in MSW?  This seems like a pretty straightforward use case for a mature technology?

Comment: A quick Google search shows that this is a known issue, with the [bug report](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=79604) being opened and unresolved for 4+ years.

Comment: I need a tool that my semi-technical customers can use to enter data directly into database tables.  The fact that they need to debug the auto-generated SQL for this scenario makes MSW no longer acceptable for semi-technical customers.  Can you recommend a free client tool MSW without quirks like this?  Overall, MSW seems like a decent tool for semi-technical customers, but little quirks like this make it unacceptable for semi-technical custimers

Comment: IMO, if your customers do not know how to write SQL themselves, they have no business directly modifying a database. You're just asking for trouble. If they need to be able to modify values, build an interface for doing so, with the appropriate checks and balances in place to ensure the continued validity and integrity of the data.